# gzip javascript files to the browser faster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, zip, client

I'm using node.js (not socket.io, im using ws and flash fall backs) I would like some opinions on serving js files as gzipped / zipped files. I have googled but I'm not sure I know enough to understand. So before I continue to google I think it is a good idea to see what you have to say about my cheddar cheese idea and perhaps help me clean my brain of silly questions.

1. what does the browser do with zipped js files? (I think nothing, it will download it to your computer as a zip file).
2. is there something for unzipping and adding js as a script tag (I think still it will be from the server to 'do you want to keep this file, this file may harm your computer [yes][no]?')
3. is this someting todo with htaccess or does the client do it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the browser does with the files depends on the http headers that the server provides in the response. For instance, we serve our gzipped scripts with the following headers:

```
Content-Type: text/javascript
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Style sheets are delivered the same way, but with content type `text/css`. The browser automatically unzips them and then processes them exactly as if they were delivered unzipped. This includes Ajax requests.

For static, gzipped files, we use the .htaccess file on our Apache server for this. Here are the relevant lines:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddCharset utf-8 .css
    AddCharset utf-8 .js
    AddEncoding gzip .gz
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "(\.js|\.js\.gz)$">
    ForceType text/javascript
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "(\.css|\.css\.gz)$">
    ForceType text/css
</FilesMatch>
```

For dynamic content, the server script generates the headers as well as the response.

Comment: so it is automatic with proper headers!

Comment: @BenMuircroft - Yep. It's quite nice.

Comment: with the ajax or json could i also zip base 64 data? AddCharset for ajax or normal req?? or don't need htaccess for that, just headers?

Comment: @BenMuircroft - You can gzip it. Note that gzip and zip are different. Stick with gzip (or compress or deflate) for compatibility. Check out the [Wikipedia article on HTTP compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) and the [HTTP spec on content encoding](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.5). The response needs to have the headers; whether they get there via .htaccess or by other means is irrelevant.

Comment: "For dynamic content, the server script generates the headers as well as the response." so are you saying that the magic of Apache lets you write this instruction once then your whole site runs faster by serving each req as zip and res as a unzip code?

Comment: @BenMuircroft - If the script generates gzipped content, the script also adds a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header to the response. Each scripting language has its own way(s) of adding such headers.

Comment: i think i understand. so Appache tells the server to always gzip responses. and because gizpped responses always gain the header of Content-Type: text/javascript
Content-Encoding: gzip - the browser always deflates them as js/json/ajax to be read as normal by the app? I don't have to add the headers to my server side code. Just do the Apache part

Comment: @BenMuircroft - Um, Apache _is_ the HTTP server. Apache handles requests for static content all on its own and you can direct a lot of this through .htaccess. Apache invokes your server-side code to process requests for dynamic content (CGI, PHP, etc.) and delivers the output of your server-side code back to the requestor. Since Apache doesn't know what your code is doing, it relies on your code to set the correct headers (including `Content-Type` and, if applicable, `Content-Encoding`).

Comment: @BenMuircroft - Note that there's a MIME type `application/x-gzip`. If you set the response to have `Content-Type: application/x-gzip`, then all this decoding magic by the browser doesn't happen. (The browser will simply save the response as a downloaded file.) You need to set the `Content-Type` to be the type of the content before compression and use the `Content-Encoding` header to signal to the browser that the content is compressed.